# My javascript is working on Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, compatibility

I'll attach the code below but you can also view the page source at [hectorcampoblog.com](https://hectorcampoblog.com/) and see the browser incompatibility in real time. I know javascript is notorious for browser incompatibility but does anyone have suggestions for this newbie self-taught coder to save me from future headaches in the future? Like are there applications that exist that check for this? or maybe a forum that teaches all the common mistakes? I'm grasping at straws here.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', reveal);{
  function reveal (){
    let reveals = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');

    for(let i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++){
/*
*i stands for iteration is the repetition of a process in a computer program, usually done with the help of loops.
*Instead of variable = variable + 1; You can type  variable += 1; Or varibale++;
*You can also  use -= , *= , /= , or instead of ++ use --
*/
      let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      let revealTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
/*The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns a DOMRect object providing information about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport*/
      let revealPoint = 150;

      if (revealTop < windowHeight - revealPoint){
        reveals[i].classList.add('active');
      }
      else {
        reveals[i].classList.remove('active');
/*
*As you scroll it adds 'active' to the end of any div CLASS ending in 'reveal' or removes 'active' as you scroll past
*You can now style the class with active and the class without active
*/`your text`
```

My guess is there's syntax issue preventing the 'active' to be added to the 'reveal' classes. I've added a '.' in front of both 'active', removed the '.' in front of 'reveal', changed the revealPoint to 0, and changed innerHeight to just Height with no luck.

Comment: I created a codesandbox, and it works for me. the code you shared is missing three } at the end. but other than that it works (i did on scroll to change the bg color to red when active class added) https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-cdn-x53j8y?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I forgot to add the missing 3 } at the end of my question but they were there. I noticed you eliminated an unnecessary {} from the code and changed the revealPoint from 150 to 300 and now it works in Chrome. Thank you so much for your help!